# The block type "sonata.admin.block.admin_list" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-cmf

I just tried to install Symfony CMF with Sonata Admin bundle but have some issues enabling it. Apparently I'm not the first, but the other answers have not helped me wery much unfortunatly.

This is my complete exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The block type "sonata.admin.block.admin_list" does not exist") in SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig at line 35.

And this is my AppKernel.php:

```
$bundles = array(
    // Symfony Standard Edition Bundles
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),

    // Symfony CMF Standard Edition Bundles
    new Doctrine\Bundle\PHPCRBundle\DoctrinePHPCRBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle(),
    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\CmfCoreBundle(),
    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\ContentBundle\CmfContentBundle(),
    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\RoutingBundle\CmfRoutingBundle(),
    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\SimpleCmsBundle\CmfSimpleCmsBundle(),

    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\BlockBundle\CmfBlockBundle(),
    new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
    new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),

    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MenuBundle\CmfMenuBundle(),
    new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),

    new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CreateBundle\CmfCreateBundle(),
    new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
    new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),

    new Sonata\jQueryBundle\SonatajQueryBundle(),
    new Sonata\DoctrinePHPCRAdminBundle\SonataDoctrinePHPCRAdminBundle(),
    new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),

    // Remove this Bundle when using the SE as the basis for a new project
    new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle(),
);
```

My relevant config.yml parts:

```
# Sonata
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
          contexts: [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu:
        sonata.user.block.account:
        sonata.block.service.text:
```

And in the end my routing:

```
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I belive I have folloed the instructions, and my only change is adding my IP to app_dev.php. I have also tried clearing my cache without any results....

Comment: I have a similar error

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that your sonata_block config is not read or maybe it is overwritten.

Could you check if you have a duplicate definition for it in one of your config files (config*.yml)?

Comment: Hi! Nope, config_dev or config_prod dosnt contain anything sonata related :/

Answer (score 0):

I beat my head on this for a while, and by adding a debug dump of the block loaders in `Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockLoaderChain::load()`, I was able to see that my block loader was returning `true` by default on `if ($loader->support($block)) {...`.  That trumped the Sonata service loader, which should be the one to support (and load) that block.  The loaders:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => BlockLoader {#617 ▼
    #entityManager: DoctrineORMEntityManager_000000005e8b2927000000004be687142a8746960d6f2b18cb3522b67eef8a8d {#208 …2}
    #types: array:3 [▼
      0 => "cmf.block.action"
      1 => "cmf.block.container"
      2 => "cmf.block.simple"
    ]
  }
  1 => ServiceLoader {#618 ▼
    #types: array:1 [▼
      0 => "sonata.admin.block.admin_list"
    ]
  }
]
```

Reason being that my loader is extending the `ServiceLoader`, and `->support($block)` is just checking if the block meta array contains a 'type'.

So I added my own `support()` method to my block loader, which will now only support types that I have defined.  Here's the entire loader:

```
namespace ExampleBundle\Cms\Loader;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Loader\ServiceLoader;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;

/**
 * ORM block loader.
 */
class BlockLoader extends ServiceLoader
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const TYPE_ACTION = 'cmf.block.action';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const TYPE_CONTAINER = 'cmf.block.container';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const TYPE_SIMPLE = 'cmf.block.simple';

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

        parent::__construct(array(
            self::TYPE_ACTION,
            self::TYPE_CONTAINER,
            self::TYPE_SIMPLE,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load($configuration): BlockInterface
    {
        $blockDefault = parent::load($configuration);

        $block = $this->getRepository($configuration['type'])->findOneByName($configuration['name']);

        return $block instanceof BlockInterface ? $block : $blockDefault;
    }

    /**
     * Get the repository for a given block type.
     *
     * @param string $type The block type.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\Repository
     */
    protected function getRepository(string $type): EntityRepository
    {
        foreach ($this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata() as $metadata) {
            if ($metadata->discriminatorValue === $type) {
                $baseName = str_replace($metadata->namespace . '\\', '', $metadata->name);
                return $this->entityManager->getRepository(sprintf('CmsBlock:%s', $baseName));
            }
        }

        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Could not find repository for block type "%s%.', $type));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function support($configuration)
    {
        if (parent::support($configuration) && $this->exists($configuration['type'])) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```